# Getting data from XML file

Tags: php, xml

I try to get data from XML file. The data looks like this:

```
<MeasuringPoints>
 <MeasuringPoint ID="Base" LastChange="2013-05-17T09:29:59.293" WeatherCondition="8">
   <Name LngID="IT">Name 1</Name>
   <Name LngID="DE">Name 2</Name>
   <Name LngID="EN>Name 3</Name>
 </MeasuringPoint>
 <MeasuringPoint ID="Middle" LastChange="2012-08-01T11:47:33.160" WeatherCondition="14">
   <Name LngID="IT">Name 1a</Name>
   <Name LngID="DE">Name 2a</Name>
   <Name LngID="EN">Name 3a</Name>
 </MeasuringPoint>
 <MeasuringPoint ID="Top" LastChange="2013-05-17T09:29:59.293" WeatherCondition="8">
   <Name LngID="DE">Name 1b</Name>
   <Name LngID="IT">Name 2b</Name>
   <Name LngID="EN">Name 3b</Name>
 </MeasuringPoint>
</MeasuringPoints>
```

I also have this php code:

```
foreach ($xml->Area as $area) 
{    
   $MEASURING_POINTS = $area->MeasuringPoints->MeasuringPoint['ID'];
   $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE = $area->MeasuringPoints->MeasuringPoint['LastChange'];

   echo $MEASURING_POINTS;
   echo " - ";
   echo $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE;
}
```

The code is working but only for first `MeasuringPoint` (the `Base` ID).

How to get the data from other `MeasuringPoint` (`Middle` and `Top` ID)?

Thanks for any help!

Adrian

Comment: Why aren't you iterating through `MeasuringPoints` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iteratore over `MeasuringPoint`.

Try this:

```
foreach ($xml->Area as $area) 
{    
   foreach($area->MeasuringPoints->MeasuringPoint as $point) {
      $MEASURING_POINT = $point['ID'];
      $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE = $point['LastChange'];

      echo $MEASURING_POINT;
      echo " - ";
      echo $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE;
   }
}
```

To only get the third MeasuringPoint try this:

```
foreach ($xml->Area as $area) 
{    
   $point = $area->xpath("/MeasuringPoints/MeasuringPoint[@ID='Top']")
   $MEASURING_POINT = $point['ID'];
   $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE = $point['LastChange'];

   echo $MEASURING_POINT;
   echo " - ";
   echo $MEASURING_LAST_CHANGE;
}
```

Comment: I have one more question - Is it possible to get data only from  `MeasuringPoint ID="Top"` section?

Comment: Sure, but in this case you have to use X-Path. See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php for the method and http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/ for an short introduction. I updated the answer for your specific case.